# I need a regex expression to make some substitutions

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to write a regex expression to turn the following string:

```
1, Pneumonectomy | 2, Lobectomy | 3, Bilobectomy | 4, Sleeve resection lobectomy | 5, Segmentectomy | 6, Wedge resection | 7, Lung resection + chest wall, diaphragm | 8, Lung volume reduction type resection | 9, Exploratory thoracotomy / no resection | 100, Other
```

Into

```
1 = "Pneumonectomy" 2 = "Lobectomy" 3 = "Bilobectomy" 4 = "Sleeve resection lobectomy" 5 = "Segmentectomy" 6 = "Wedge resection" 7 = "Lung resection + chest wall, diaphragm" 8 = "Lung volume
```

Where each vertical pipe is replaced with a double quote then a space, and the first comma after the pipe is replaced with an equals sign then a double quote.

I can match using:

```
'\s*\|\s*'
```

is substituted by

```
'" '
```

But I am struggling to work out how I can replace only the first comma after the pipe.

Eventually, I will be implementing this in SAS, suing something like:

```
format_string = prxchange('s/\s*\|\s*/" "/', -1, select_choices_or_calculations);
format_string = prxchange('s/\s*,\s*/ = "/', -1, format_string);
```

Comment: There's no pipe before `1,` but you replaced it with `=`.

Comment: It seems like you just want to replace every comma with an equal sign and remove all the pipes.

Comment: I only want the first occurence of the comma in each substring - number 7 is Lung resection + chest wall, diaphragm

Comment: Sounds like you should first split it using pipe as the delimiter, replace the first comma in each item with equal, then join it back together with space delimiters.

Comment: I don't know SAS, so I don't know how easy that is.

Comment: `(\d+),\s*([^|]+[\|\s])(?:$|\s*\|)` => `$1 = "$2" ` It gets annoying if you're not sure of the spacing around the pipe and first comma.

Comment: Similar to the other rexex `\s*(\d+),\s*([^|]*?)\s*?(?:\||$)` https://regex101.com/r/kERaCs/1

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the job. Adapt as needed:

`(\d+),\s+(\w+(?>\s[\w\+\/,]+)*)(\s\|\s)?`

Use this for the substitution:

`$1 = "$2"`

You can test the expression here: https://regex101.com/r/JxiAxr/1